# Regex laravel validation

Tags: php, regex, validation

Hello everyone I'm trying to validate if input has correct data. I need to check it input is number in pattern xx,xx or xxx. For example if user put 100 or 120,32 it will pass the validation. I'm trying to make regular expression for this but I'm not good in this topic. I have working code for xx,xx but how can I add to check first or second option to don't throw an error? Here is what I've got:

```
/^[+]?\d+\,\d+/
```

Answer (score 0):

**Your question**

For the examples you mentioned, this would match all occurences:

```
/\d{2,3}(,\d{2})?)/
```

It says (in basic english): Two to three digits, followed by an optional "comma and two digits". For explanation, also see the example on Regex101: https://regex101.com/r/hU5kJ7/1

However I do not see any reason why you would limit the digits before the floating point to 3 digits, so to make it open, you could just leave out the 3:

```
/\d{2,}(,\d{2})?)/
```

It says (in basic english): Two to unlimited digits, followed by an optional "comma and two digits".

**Apart from that**

I would really not recommend implementing something that basic like number (or currency?) validation by yourself again. It is like reinventing the wheel. You will find many and many validation implementations like that all over the internet, in so called validation libraries or frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

This regex should solve your problem:

```
/^\d+(,\d+)?/
```